# C# WPF Select ComboBox Item By DataGrid SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgiRR.png)Hello Guys I've searched around and haven't really found a clear answer.
How to Select ComboBox Item By DataGrid SelectedItem using DataBinding
when a DataGrid Rwo is selected, the ComboBox must change to match the DataGrid cell value.
My DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DatagridGroup" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding GroupList}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

My ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComGroupType"
      ItemsSource="{Binding GroupTypeList}"
      DisplayMemberPath="GroupTypeName"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroupType,Mode=TwoWay, 
      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

my ViewModel

```
private Group selectedGroup = new Group();
    public Group SelectedGroup
    {
        get => selectedGroup;
        set
        {
            selectedGroup = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedGroup));
            selectedGroupType = value.GType;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(selectedGroupType));
        }
    }
    private GroupType selectedGroupType = new DebitCredit();
    public GroupType SelectedGroupType
    {
        get => selectedGroupType;
        set
        {
            selectedGroupType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(selectedGroupType));
        }
    }
```

My Model

```
 public class Group
    {
        private GroupType gType = new GroupType();
        private int groupID;
        private int groupNumber;
        private string groupName;
        private int groupTypeID;
        private string groupTypeName;

        public GroupType GType
        {
            get => gType;
            set
            { gType = value; }
        }
        public int GroupID
        {
            get => groupID;
            set
            { groupID = value; }
        }
        public int GroupNumber
        {
            get => groupNumber;
            set
            { groupNumber = value; }
        }
        public string GroupName
        {
            get => groupName;
            set
            { groupName = value; }
        }
        public int GroupTypeID
        {
            get => groupTypeID;
            set
            {
                groupTypeID = value;
                gType.GroupTypeID = value;
            }
        }
        public string GroupTypeName
        {
            get => groupTypeName;
            set
            {
                groupTypeName = value;
                gType.GroupTypeName = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am new to MVVM and I did not find any previous question that explains this idea

Comment: in viewmodel, when `SelectedGroup` set, update `SelectedGroupType` value.

Comment: paste in the question, not comment.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged` should always use the properties' name(the upper case ones). please  edit and try again.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I tried that and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Set the `SelectedGroupType` *property* in the setter of `SelectedGroup`:

```
public Group SelectedGroup
{
    get => selectedGroup;
    set
    {
        selectedGroup = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedGroup));
        SelectedGroupType = value.GType;
    }
}
```

You also need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the *property*:

```
public GroupType SelectedGroupType
{
    get => selectedGroupType;
    set
    {
        selectedGroupType = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedGroupType));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could bind directly to the `SelectedItem` of the `DataGrid`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComGroupType"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GroupTypeList}"
    DisplayMemberPath="GroupTypeName"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.GType, ElementName=DatagridGroup}"/>
```